# Mysql query to find hackers who made at least 1 submission each day

Tags: mysql

I want to find all the hackers who made at least 1 submission each day.

Table looks like: id, date.

```
1, 2016-01-01
2, 2016-01-01
3, 2016-01-01
1, 2016-01-02
2, 2016-01-02
1, 2016-01-03
```

So the output should be:
1
Since 1 has made submission on all the day.

What I have tried is:

```
Select id from table 
group by id
having count(*)=3 /* Since number of days are 3 */
```

However this is incorrect because a hacker can make multiple submissions on a day. 
Example where my query will fail:

```
1, 2016-01-01
2, 2016-01-01
3, 2016-01-01
3, 2016-01-01
3, 2016-01-01
1, 2016-01-02
2, 2016-01-02
1, 2016-01-03
```

After this is solved, the original question is:

Write a query to print total number of unique hackers who made at least submission each day (starting on the first day of the contest), and find the hacker_id and name of the hacker who made maximum number of submissions each day. If more than one such hacker has a maximum number of submissions, print the lowest hacker_id. The query should print this information for each day of the contest, sorted by the date

Comment: Alternatively, can you think of a query to find all hackers who *didn't* submit every day? Your desired result would be the inverse of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe if you group by both `id` and `date` you'll get what you're looking for. i.e.:

```
SELECT id
FROM table 
GROUP BY id, `date`
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3 /* Since number of days are 3 */
```

Note that this assumes you are getting the number of days (3 in this case) based on some date range from somewhere else.

Comment: Write a query to print total number of unique hackers who made at least  submission each day (starting on the first day of the contest), and find the hacker_id and name of the hacker who made maximum number of submissions each day. If more than one such hacker has a maximum number of submissions, print the lowest hacker_id. The query should print this information for each day of the contest, sorted by the date.

Comment: You can't return "total number of unique hackers" and "find the hacker_id and name" in the same query - those seem like two different queries to me. Having said that, to achieve your 2nd request you'd have to join against a sub-select. Assuming you don't have very large number of rows, an alternative would be to return all eligible rows per above query - i.e. add `COUNT(*) AS total` to the select, and `ORDER BY total DESC, id ASC` at the end - and then have the application logic take the first row for each date. You should try both ways, and ask another question. I don't have enough room here.

Comment: apparantly this didn't work now. Please use below @Gordon Linoff answer now.

Comment: @Krissh it works - for working example with data from the question, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00f96d/1

Answer (score 1):

I would phrase this as:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having count(distinct date) = (select count(distinct date) from t);
```