# SQL Advanced Join using multiple aggregations

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi guys i was trying to solve a problem using sql in the below link

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/15-days-of-learning-sql/problem

I have written the following sql query and was getting incorrect result.please help where i am going wrong

```
SELECT s.submission_date,COUNT(DISTINCT(s.hacker_id)),s1.hacker_id, h.name
FROM  Hackers h INNER JOIN Submissions s ON (h.hacker_id = s.hacker_id)  
                INNER JOIN Submissions s1 ON s1.hacker_id = s.hacker_id
Where s1.hacker_id = (
SELECT w.hacker_id from 
                      (
                      SELECT hacker_id, COUNT(hacker_id)from Submissions s
                      GROUP BY s.submission_date,hacker_id
                      ORDER BY COUNT(hacker_id) desc, hacker_id ASC  
                      limit 1 
                      ) w
)
GROUP BY s.submission_date,s1.hacker_id,h.name
ORDER BY s.submission_date ASC;
```

Actual Output is

```
2016-03-03 1 80682 Deborah 
2016-03-04 1 80682 Deborah 
2016-03-07 1 80682 Deborah 
2016-03-14 1 80682 Deborah
```

The Sample Output is

```
2016-03-01 4 20703 Angela
2016-03-02 2 79722 Michael
2016-03-03 2 20703 Angela
2016-03-04 2 20703 Angela
```

Please suggest modification in the same code rather than new code if possible.
Thanks

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. Remove those redundant parentheses to make the code clearer, i.e. do `COUNT(DISTINCT s.hacker_id)`!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql query to find hackers who made at least 1 submission each day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035625/mysql-query-to-find-hackers-who-made-at-least-1-submission-each-day)

Comment: @hotfix this questions has 4 columns as output and has other expectations. So it is not a duplicate question.Please refer the complete problem in the link. Thanks

Comment: @prasannakumar have you tried to google that problem? this could help https://nifannn.github.io/2017/10/24/SQL-Notes-Hackerrank-Contest-Leaderboard/

Comment: a big thanks @hotfix.I will refer the link you provided which seems to be useful.